# Can't write data in text file through Python script

Tags: python-3.x, network-share

I'm using Python 3.6.4. I'm trying to send the file on a network.
Here is my code. When I try to execute it, it goes to infinite loop and my file remains 0kb.

```
f = open(f_name+'.txt', 'wb')
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data == "":
        break
    f.write(data)

f.close()
print("File closed")

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this where you explicitly `return False` instead of break.  Also, I'd open your connection outside of the while loop to make sure you aren't starting over with pulling data each time.

```
    f = open(f_name+'.txt', 'wb')
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    while True:

        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if data != "":
            f.write(data)
        else:
            return False

    f.close()
    print("File closed")
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Return cannot be used in loop